# Using both mysql and redis in yii2 application

Tags: php, mysql, redis, yii2

I'm building a CRM system which should allow a different access for different users, so i need to make a complex authentication and notifications in the panel. But the main system should use the REDIS. I have installed yii2 redis plugin and have the config like this in db.php (mysql config  ):

```
<?php
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    // Schema cache options (for production environment)
    //'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    //'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
    //'schemaCache' => 'cache',
];
```

And in web.php:

```
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],

'components' => [
        'redis'         => [

            'class'    => 'yii\redis\Connection',

            'hostname' => 'localhost',

            'port'     => 6379,

            'database' => 0,

        ],
     ],
     'db' => $db,
```

How can i differntiate my models, to use either mysql or redis? I assume if i specify redis in components section, the whole app uses redis db. I could use redis with multiple values for key, but since redis is dropping the keys when max memory will be reached, all registered users and their profiles will parish, so i think i should use mysql for this basci stuff ( database with roles, authentification, profiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return [
   'components' => [
      'db1' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1name', //maybe other dbms such as psql,...
        'username' => 'db1username',
        'password' => 'db1password',
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'YOURCONFIG', 
        'port' => '6379',
        'password' => 'db2password',
        'username' => 'db2username',
    ],
  ],
];
```

Then try to use

```
// To get from db1
Yii::$app->db1->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')->from('tbl_name'))->queryAll()

// To get from db2
Yii::$app->db2->createCommand((new \yii\db\Query)->select('*')->from('tbl_name'))->queryAll();
```

For active record in your model write

```
// db1
public function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->db1;
}

//Or db2
public function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->db2;
}
```

Comment: Hi if this help you can you vote the answer it will help me to improve my account